# Setting layout properties in code at runtime

Tags: xamarin.android

I am having trouble finding out how to set layout properties in my code.
My controls are being generated at runtime so I can't set the layout in my xml.

I would like to be able to set properties such as

android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_weight="1"

However I can't find any documentation or examples on how to do this in code.
Is it possible with the current version of Mono for Android?

Answer (score 10):

[Relevant thread on the Mono for Android mailing list.](http://lists.ximian.com/mailman/private/monodroid/2011-April/004556.html)

Many of the constructors take an [IAttributeSet](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=T%3aAndroid.Util.IAttributeSet) instance, so (worst case) you could always provide the XML custom attributes through that parameter when invoking the e.g. [RelativeLayout(Context, IAttributeSet) constructor](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=C%3aAndroid.Widget.RelativeLayout(Android.Content.Context%2cAndroid.Util.IAttributeSet)).

Resource attributes are handled specifically in Java code, and thus can potentially vary from one class to another. For example, the [RelativeLayout constructor implementation](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/RelativeLayout.java;h=a47359f8a6a4c7c4e1b9a2cbd16e8e929b3bd01b;hb=HEAD#l172).

Because of this, attributes can (and will be) specific to a given type. For example, as best as I can tell from quickly perusing the Android source, it's not valid for a type to have both `android:layout_alignParentBottom` and `android:layout_weight` attributes, as [android:layout_alignParentBottom](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_alignParentBottom) appears to be specific to the `RelativeLayout` type, while [android:layout_weight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_weight) is specific to [LinearLayout](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=T%3aAndroid.Widget.LinearLayout), and there is no inheritance relationship between `RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout`.

That said, to programmatically assign the `android:layout_alignParentBottom` property, it looks like you'd want to do:

```
// Get a RelativeLayout.LayoutParams instance
// Option 1, if you have an existing RelativeLayout instance already:
var p = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) layout.LayoutParameters;

// Option 2: if you don't.
var p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams (context, null);

// Enable layout_alignParentBottom:
p.AddRule ((int) LayoutRules.AlignParentBottom);
```

This uses the [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.AddRule](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=M%3aAndroid.Widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.AddRule(System.Int32)) method to enable the layout option. The `int` cast is necessary because we didn't realize that `AddRule()` should take a `LayoutRules` enum; oops.

To programmatically assign the `android:layout_alignParentRight` property:

```
p.AddRule ((int) LayoutRules.AlignParentRight);
```

As noted above, it appears that [android:layout_weight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_weight) is specific to `LinearLayout`, so we can't use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` to set this. Instead, we need to use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` to set the [LinearLayout.LayoutParams.Weight](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=P%3aAndroid.Widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.Weight) property:

```
// Just like before, but get a LinearLayout.LayoutParams instance
// Option 1, if you have an existing LinearLayout instance already:
var p = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) layout.LayoutParameters;

// Option 2: if you don't.
var p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams (context, null);

// Enable layout_weight:
p.Weight = 1.0f;
```