# MonoDroid: How to programatically set TableRow background attribute?

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm trying to dynamically create some table rows, but on the Table Row I want to set the background
attribute like this XML:

<TableRow android:background="@drawable/shape" android:layout_marginBottom="5dip">

I tried this:

TableRow.LayoutParams p = new TableRow.LayoutParams(this, null);

but there is no p.AddRule method? (as quoted from: [Setting layout properties in code at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805007/setting-layout-properties-in-code-at-runtime))

I think I need to construct the params then pass them into the 
TableRow row = new TableRow(this, p);

Ideas?

Comment: Well, I guess what I really need is an IAttributeSet to pass into the TableRow constructor.

Comment: Figured it out:

 row.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.shape);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: row.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.shape);

Answer (score 0):

`AddRule()` is a method on `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`. You need to either cast to that type or acquire it otherwise, i.e. :

```
var p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams (this, null);
p.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentBottom);
```